# 6.1 Jólnir Permanent Freeze on startup

Tags: boot, release-jolnir

I have been using Eos for about 3
Months now on my Framework laptop with no issues but recently, the computer will freeze after a login after some suspends or restarts.

After a suspend or restart I am able to enter my password and the desktop appears but I am only able to move the mouse for 5-10 seconds before everything freezes.

The only way I’ve been able to fix it is to do a hard shut down and wait ~30 min before turning it back on.

I am able to access BIOS and GRUB, and I was able boot Eos from a micosd without issue, which leads me to think that there is something wrong with Eos rather than the BIOS or hardware or something.

Please help! I’ve no idea what to do to fix this.

Comment: Did you manage to sort out this issue? I'm asking because I'm considering buying a Framework laptop at some point.

Comment: @DaneRossenrode Unfortunately I have not been able to figure out what happened. I’ve been using Ubuntu for now and even that has some issues with settings getting messed up. I’m hesitant to try to go back to elementary as I use my computer for work and I was forced to wipe that hard drive after it started freezing  on 95% of boot ups.